# Can we delete events created by another user(Google App account)?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

Can we delete calendar events created by another user(Google App account) using Google App script?.

I would like to have a list of events created by a particular user along with the calendar event details and then i want to delete some events among those.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: For Google Apps Script, the event should be shared to you. Just a few clarifications, are you referring to a list of events shared to you by a particular user and you want to delete some of those shared events which were already added into your calendar?

Comment: No..I have super admin access to a domain. I want to delete events created by a suspended user in a calendar resource, Since other users ca n not remove this, I have to remove those entries using Google app script.